# How to avoid/reduce heat for three 1W LED's?

Tags: led, voltage, heatsink

I'm asking on behalf of a colleague who wanted to make solar powered lighting for poor people.
Electricity generated by solar cells are stored in a car-battery sized 12V battery, and that current is passed to three 1W LED's which operate at 3.3V. She's tried connecting it in series and parallel, but she says the circuit heats up and the LED's don't work for a while, but when it cools down, the LED's glow again.

She wanted to know:
1. How to prevent the heat formation, so that the LED's would glow continuously?
2. How to efficiently convert 12V to the three 3.3V of the LED's (series/parallel)

Using thermal paste was far too expensive (they're making it for poor people).

Comment: You need to put restistor/s in series with LEDs, otherwise you will kill them if they don't happen to have protection against that.

Comment: Can you confirm that these LED's either include their own driver circuitry, or you've omitted to mention your friend having built or included appropriate driver circuitry in the mix here? The easiest solution IMHO is to use off-the-shelf MR16 LED lamps as they are designed to run straight from 12v.

Comment: You very clearly have an optimization problem in which you don't have all the variable defined.  As a case in point, you are using (3) expensive LED's (1W) but cannot use thermal paste (which is very inexpensive).  It makes more sense for you to tell us the costs of your components, the desired light levels and the (which has been ignored so far) desired efficiency.  It seems to me that if this is very cost sensitive that the best (defined as lowest cost, longest time running) solution is the target.  If you can redefine your problem I'm 100% certain people here will jump right on it.

Comment: If you're trying to capture energy using solar panels, why waste 3W of that energy on making LEDs glow? LEDs are pretty bright without needing that much power..need more details of design.

Comment: The best way to avoid heat is to **NOT** use a resistor or Linear solution (as many suggest here), but instead use a switching converter. **[Russell McMahon provided a very affordable answer using discrete-only solutions, one using a FET, and another using only BJT's.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/173841/146624)**  If you can't make it work, ask around, or I might be able to help. If all else fails, use 24V to 48V of LED's in series and use a discrete boost converter like the Joule Thief (but with the base-emitter zenering problem fixed). Again, ask around, or ask me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only two ways to reduce heat in LED applications. The first is undercurrent. Reduce the current they use by choosing bigger resistors or adjusting your current controlled source. This of course leads to less light output. Alternatively you can use PWM to simulate the brightness but still cutting out some on cycles.

The other method is cooling. Large Heatsinks are the primary passive method. Or you can throw on a fan as well. There is always Peltiers but cost is a concern with those.

You do not want the leds in parallel. You will need to bring down the 12v to 3.3v on each, and then have three times the current. Very inefficient. Keep it in series, you would only need a single current regulator and only one times the current.

Comment: Surely cooling just reduces temperature, not heat?

Comment: @Cybergibbons no practical difference. Reducing temperature is how you dissipate heat. Using a heat sink allows the heat from the LEDs spread into something with a larger surface, which allows both passive radiation, and any air movement to help transfer the heat into the air. Basically the goal is to remove the heat faster than it can be generated.

Comment: @Passerby Heat is the transfer of energy, temperature is the energy itself.

Comment: @gunnish yes, but this is EE stack, not http://physics.stackexchange.com/ :P It's a practical approximation.

Comment: Have a look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31586/how-to-know-how-many-leds-can-be-used-at-a-given-voltage it explains what's needed assuming these are LED's without any built-in current limiting circuit

Comment: The problem was finally solved with an old device (forgot the name) which ignored some of the AC cycles and only sent some of the AC cycles to the circuit, which converted those cycles into DC.

Comment: @Nav ignored some of AC cycles? You mean like a half wave rectifier?